# How can I build an IVR on Windows

Tags: sql-server, windows, asterisk, ivr

I need to build an IVR system on Windows 
I installed asterisk win32 on windows and I was able to create a dialplan. I was able to read from Database (MSSQL). the only problem I got while configuring asterisk on Windows is converting the Text to speech. every time I use Festival I got "festival_client: connect to server failed". I even used the googletts.agi and I installed the sox exchanger and mpg123 but I could not hear any sound.

so please help me solve this problem or if there is an alternative to asterisk that can connect to MSSQL and I can use Arabic voice and it can be installed on Windows I would appreciate your help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: have you made sure that festival's attempts to connect to server are not being blocked by your firewall ?

Comment: `voicent` is a commercial product that might help

Answer (score -1):

Asterisk win32 is not stable and probably have security issues(they not fix issues found in asterisk core).

On windows even if you use vmware image with asterisk - that will be more stable.

It is hard to answer your question, becuase googletts.agi not use festival, so not clear what exactly you using. Seams like you have windows security level/firewall issues, but no way say exactly.

ps Debug is offtopic on SO

Comment: when I failed to hear sound while using Festival, I searched and found that I'm able to use googletts.agi but it also was a failure

Comment: Yes, becuase you have change it if you run under windows(almost compleatly). It is linux script.

Comment: is there any alternatives that I can use instead of googletts.agi on windows?

Comment: You should write your own script on windows. Linux script will not work without rewrite.